# DataTable : How to style filter result as type?

Tags: jquery, css

- I want to style my filter result as I type.
- For example, if I type `bs-` I want to highlight all the result containing `bs-`
- How do I do that in CSS ?

I am using a [DataTable](http://www.datatables.net/).

[image]

Comment: To be clear, you only want to highlight matched searched terms? And do no filtering?
(By definition, the filter will only display matching rows, so no need to visually highlight)

Comment: I understand that, but I just want to give my users a little more interaction as they type.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **@sdcr** for pointing me to the right direction.

I accomplish that by doing the following :

1- Include JS CDN

```
<script src="//bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/f2c75b7247b/features/searchHighlight/dataTables.searchHighlight.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

2- Include CSS CDN

3- Add `"searchHighlight": true` as part of your setting.

My whole setting look like this :

```
// Setting to Inventory Table 
  $('#inventory').dataTable({

    "lengthMenu": [ 10 ] ,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "searchHighlight": true

  });
```

My final result :

[image]

Comment: I also suggest you to download the js files you use above, and load them from you site assets. so you found the answer?

Comment: Thanks, I will do that. I scroll down all the way to the bottom and then I saw it. [http://www.datatables.net/blog/2014-10-22](http://www.datatables.net/blog/2014-10-22)